Control or configure consistent gdb path handling
When I run gdb.exe with a RELATIVE path to my executable file "app", eg:
gdb target/debug/app
it has no problem finding the file and reading symbols, giving me the output:
Reading symbols from target/debug/app... and then moving on to the gdb prompt.
However, after connecting to the remote target, I then get an error:
BFD: reopening C:\target\debug\app: No such file or directory
Why is gdb interpreting the path correctly (as relative) at the original invocation, but then appending this path to "C:\" as if it's an ABSOLUTE path for the subsequent reopening step?
I'm using "GNU gdb (GNU Tools for STM32 12.3.rel1.20240612-1315) 13.2.90.20230627-git" for debugging on an STM32 MCU.
EDIT:  there isn't much more to show, but here is the full session:
MY CMD INPUT:  arm-none-eabi-gdb ./target/debug/app


GNU gdb (GNU Tools for STM32 12.3.rel1.20240612-1315) 13.2.90.20230627-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./target/debug/app...
(gdb) target remote :3333
Remote debugging using :3333
BFD: reopening C:\target\debug\app: No such file or directory


Could you include a full GDB session up to the error, this might make it easier to track down what's going wrong.
